# Getting debug information from your users

Tags: iphone

If one of your beta testers has problems with your app crashing, how do you usually go about debugging this if it works fine for yourself/other users?

Is there a way to have debug information sent to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html) should help. It includes a section **Instructions for Application Testers** that includes information about how testers should send crash reports to you.

You'll then be able to view the crash reports by following the instructions in the section **Importing Crash Logs from Testers**.